# How do I change the direction of an object set to "Bake Sound to F-Curves"?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, keyframes, baking, fcurves

I have an object set to "Bake Sound to F-Curves" and "LocRot". It's set to move along the z-axis. My problem is that it moves in an upward motion as pictured below. How do I make the object move in a downward motion?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you include a .blend file? You can upload it to blend exchange.

Comment: Just uploaded a .blend file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Idle Chit-chat

I assume that by "in a downward motion" you mean that you want its jittering effectively reflected over the x axis. There is a way to do this.

### Solution

Go to the *Graph Editor*, select the baked-sound f-curve, key *N* to open the Graph Editor's *Properties panel*, and open the *Modifiers* drop down menu (it should be at the bottom of the stack). Add an *Envelope* modifier and change the settings to this:

[image]

You will need to click *Add Point* before you can change the bottom-most settings (1, 0, and -1.8). This should make the cube move in a downward motion.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you determined those values?

Comment: @cegaton Trial and error. It's been a long time since I learned the modifier and I couldn't remember the specifics.